# using aws cli how to get list of tasks id per ecs service

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-cli

using AWS CLI how to get list of tasks ids per ecs services. When I use `describe-services` it  does not list task id details only the count of number of tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use the `aws ecs list-tasks --cluster <cluster-name> --service-name <service-name>` [command](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/list-tasks.html) to get a list of tasks for a specific service.